# This Question has Answers Pluralization Bug

Tags: discussion, bug, answers, hyperlinks, deleted-questions

I found in interesting bug today, I tried to delete one of my questions and it said 'sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted'.  But, in fact, it only had one answer...

[image: Bug Photo]

Comment: not really a bug just lack of a conditional statement for grammar - i dont think anyone minds too much

Comment: [status-too-minor-to-care]

Comment: "Coming to Discovery Channel this spring: Man vs. Doorknob"

Comment: Obligatory: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: "Answers" is the correct word to use here.  It's being used in the sense of "one or more answers."

Comment: I've seen such a 'bug' when a question is a duplicate: "*This question already have an answer here [link to question] ...... 1 answers .*"

Comment: Um, can *things* really be made *a bit more worse*?

Comment: Wait, why did you change your question...?

Comment: @Arjan: It's a bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218315/editing-question-title-creates-whole-new-question

Comment: Easiest fix - Answer(s)

Comment: @Ashley No it would read: *this question has answer*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suggested solution:

```
 if(Request.Cookies["userID"]="The Wobbuffet")
       throw new FaultException("Sorry, this question has ONE SINGLE Answer.");
 else
       throw new NormalException();
```

Comment: The whole world must share this solution, I am none but thou unhappiest :(

Comment: ...you mean: *"ONE SINGLE post the MIGHT be an answer?"*

Answer (score 11):

I would prefer if the whole text was changed to:

> Sorry, this question has been answered and can not be deleted.

Comment: "has been answered" implies, to me, that it has an accepted answer. Also isn't it true that a question is only blocked from being deleted if it has at least one answer *with a positive score*? Personally, I think the current wording is just fine. If the grammar police can't figure out that "answers" actually means "one or more answers", ***shrug***.

Comment: @Aaron how does the current wording imply that the question has an answer with positive score? It just says has answers.

Comment: I understand that. I'm not saying that your suggestion changes that, just that it also doesn't reflect the whole truth (and also note I said "Isn't it true?" - I don't even remember if that's the rule).

Answer (score 3):

Not quite the *same* plural bug as ones before, but obligatory [@CodingHorror status](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

> Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

I suppose this could be fixed, but it seems rather unnecessary, even though it's a simple fix. Perhaps it would be better if it said "This question has one answer*s* and cannot be deleted"

Comment: ...which was already mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Arjan when I started writing this, it wasn't in the question.

Comment: Those were [15 minutes well spent then](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/218306/timeline) ;-)

Comment: I started writing it, then got sidetracked. I can delete it if you want

Comment: No worries, though the same reference was also already made in a comment, your *"it seems rather unnecessary"* is certainly true. (And for some reason the whole question just changed, but I guess that was an error... What a mess.)