# Editing question title creates whole new question and other question list problems

Tags: bug, questions, meta

SE is really acting up today, sometimes it doesn't show any questions in the questions tab in the sites.

I first noticed the problems when I opened my questions tab, and this shows up:

> [image: Same question shows up as two]

All I did was change the name of the question, and now meta stackoverflow thinks it's two questions.  Well the thing is, MSO actually created it as a **new question!**  Why?

Comment: It seems like things were broken for the past couple of minutes; all seems well now.  (The questions tab wasn't showing anything a while back.)

Comment: @devnull No, still not "well" for me.  Same bug

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Things seem to be broken.

Comment: Yup, looks like the caching infrastructure is going haywire again.

Comment: See, the answer is always caching.

Comment: +1; I rollback'd the changed post. @Bart What about localization? :P

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Thanks, this bug thing is getting crazy

Comment: No, it's the caching infrastructure; I just marked another 6 or 7 questions as duplicates of this one, as they are all symptoms of the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps it is an existential protest against [MyOpenID closing down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442). Like [the elevators'](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Chapter_6_2).